# selecting result from two tables in form clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi i have two table A and B.A has 6 rows and b has 7 rows.Both tables have  common value in name column.All the 6 rows of a table is present in b table on name column.

When i write query select * from a,b where a.name = b.name i get 14 rows returned i was expecting an inner join of with 6 rows in result.

Please explain me how query works when we have two tables in form clause.

Table A
[image]

Table B
[image]

query is 
select * from a,b where a.tt = b.tt and a.nename=b.nename;

reuslt is 
[image]

Comment: why don't you use standard join syntax?

Comment: I can but  i am just asking what happens when we use such query,Is it a full joining happening or what is going on here ?

Answer (score 1):

You've got duplicates in both tables (except for `{2, 2017-03-04 03:00:00}` which has three copies) which is why you get 14  = (2 * 4) + (2 * 3).

It's very hard to make sense of duplicate data. It's even harder to do when it duplicated on both sides of a join.

You could do something like

```
With fixedA (SELECT 
               *, 
               row_number() over (partition by nename, tt order by nename) rn 
             FROM 
                A),
     fixedb (SELECT 
               *, 
               row_number() over (partition by nename, tt order by nename) rn 
             FROM 
                B)
      SELECT * 
      FROM fixedA a  full outer join  fixedb  b
           on a.neName = b.neName
             and a.tt = b.tt
             and a.rn = b.rn
```

This will however leave one B record with a Null A record

The row_number also seems to do what cellID does so you could just do

```
SELECT * 
          FROM a  full outer join  b
               on a.neName = b.neName
                 and a.tt = b.tt
                 and a.cellID = b.cellID
```

Comment: i can make use of inner join and get result but My question is what is currently happening in this query why 14 rows are coming

Comment: @Sunil Kumar, I think @Conrad Frix explained it very well. When you do the join, for each row in table `a` it tries to find matching rows in table `b`, if you analyze your tables closely you will find out. Try this exercise: from table `a` (based on `nename` and `tt`) try to find the rows in table `b` that match with the first row in table `a`, and print those rows (on a paper), and repeat this for each row in table `a`. You will come up with the same result.

Answer (score -1):

you should be doing something like full outer join on that table that you need result set from I would suggest something like this

```
select * from a full outer join b on a.tt = b.tt and a.nename=b.nename;
```

if your dealing with a bigger data set join on data type like varchar might take a lot of time to load the result set due to comparison. So, it would be better to use foreign key or primary key joins

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Comment: The join would result in the exact same number of records

Comment: My question is whats happening here in query  ?  i can use joins but i want to under stranded how query is performed when i use such query

Comment: a query like this select * from a,b where a.tt = b.tt and a.nename=b.nename  would take one record from a and will try to match it with all the records and returns the matched and happens with all the rows of a and b so because you have duplicate data it would return wrong result set

Comment: @ConradFrix I looked at the solution provided by you looks that we are on same page but I missed it with the duplicate records, thanks for correcting me :)